# How to I select after longpress or holding event in apache cordova visual studio community (spec for windows phone)

Tags: arrays, cordova, visual-studio-2012

We are creating a book that should select a particular text after the long press(touch) or holding the window(spec for windows phone) for highlighting the selected text. How should I select the para or word after a long press or holding the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. Just setting some conditions as below, Its working fine.

```
        $( "#wrap" ).disableSelection();

        $( "#wrap" ).bind( "taphold", getSelectedWordIndex );
        //document.addEventListener( 'select', getSelectedWordIndex, false );
        var a = 1;
        function getSelectedWordIndex()
        {
            a = 2;
            $( "#wrap" ).enableSelection();
        }

        document.addEventListener( 'select', getSelectedWordIndex1, false );

        function getSelectedWordIndex1()
        {
            if ( a == 2 )
            {
                if ( window.getSelection )
                {
                    var div = document.getElementById( "wrap" );
                    var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
                    //alert( "Left" + textRange.offsetLeft + " Top" + textRange.offsetTop );

                    $( "#menu" ).css( "top", mouseY - 30 )
                    .css( "left", mouseX + 10 ).fadeIn( "1000" );


                    a = 1;
                    $( "#wrap" ).disableSelection();
                }
            }
        }
```